# How to correctly handle different Firebase Cloud Function APIs endpoints related to two different environments (DEV and PROD)?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an Angular application deployed on Firebase.

I have the following doubt about what could be a smart strategy to handle a same application that have to be deployed on two different environment (DEV and PROD) that basically are two different Firebase projects related two different accounts.

My application perform some APIs call implemented by Firebase Cloud Function. My problem is that having two different environments the endpoints related the APIs implemented by my Firebase Cloud Functions will change.

At the moment my application works fine in DEV enviroment and these APIs endpoint are hardcoded into my code. Something like this:

```
this.apiCallUrl = "https://MY-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net/newUserSignUp?userUID=" + userCredential.user.uid;
```

And then I call the API in my Angular code performing an HTTP GET request:

```
this.http.get<any>(this.apiCallUrl).subscribe((result) => {                                                                                                
    console.log("DISABBLING STATUS USER: ", result);                                                                                               
});
```

It works fine but it is very awkward to be deployed again into another project because I have to manually change all the endpoints into my application and deploy again in PROD env (and it means that I need to have two different projects: one for the DEV environment and another one for the PROD environment).

What could be a smart solution to handle this situation?

I don't know if it is possible: Firebase allow to retrieve the enpoint of an API (implemented Google Cloud Functions) using its name? (it doesn't change). Or other possible smart approach to this problem?

Comment: Angular provide 2 different environment files if you check you can properly change it according to your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as Community Wiki as it was based in the comment.

You can try using the environment variables available in Angular to set the different API endpoints for your PROD and DEV. As clarified in this great article [here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be), with the usage of multiple environments on Angular, you can have different environment variables, where each one of them can have the endpoint names of their own.

You can get very good example of code in the official Angular API [here](https://angular.io/guide/build). Besides that, you can also check this other article [here](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/) related to deploy application in more than one environment, without rebuilding them all the time.